# Passing a type generated at RunTime (via TypeBuilder) to GenericClass

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5, reflection.emit

I would like to pass a type that is generated at runtime (via TypeBuilder) to a generic method in a generic class. I can't pass it as object as reflection is used to look up various properties.

As I understand, this can't be done as generics are applied at compile-time rather than run-time.

I know I can change an method like

```
public T Read()
{
     T data = new T()
     ...
     return data;
}
```

to be something like

```
public object Read(Type newType)
{
     object data =  Activator.CreateInstance(newType);  
     ...
     return data;
}
```

but this obviously loses all the advantages of generics when the type is known, so I will probably end with both methods, which unfortunately means also duplicating quite a few other other helper functions.

Is there any better way of resolving this issue?

This particular project needs to work under the 3.5 framework, but if it isn't possible in 3.5, but is under 4.0, I wouldn't mind knowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `Read()` is a member of `class Reader<T> where T : new()`, you can call the generic version like this (possibly using another overload of `GetMethod()` if you have more than one method with the name `Read` on that type):

```
Type readerType = typeof(Reader<>).MakeGenericType(generatedType);
object result = readerType
                  .GetMethod("Read")
                  .Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(readerType), new object[0]);
```

This way, you have the advantage of generics inside `Read()`, but not outside. Depending on what you want to do, maybe it would be better to use interfaces instead of generics. The `new()` constraint can be emulated by generating a factory type for every generated type, the types implementing the following (non-generated) interfaces:

```
interface IWhatever { … }

interface IWhateverFactory
{
    IWhatever Create();
}
```